# Regex - ignore specific strings in the middle

Tags: regex

How would I go about filtering out files that include a certain string:

Say I'm filtering file paths with the following regex

```
"/.xml$|.json$/i"
```

And I'd like to ignore files that are xml but include `_unwanted_string` in the name

For example:

> file_name_unwanted_string.xml

> SOMEOTHERNAME_unwanted_string.xml

> NAME3_unwanted_string.xml

> NAME3_unwanted_string_MORE_TEXT.xml

should all **not** be caught in the regex.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: But `/^(?!file_name_unwanted_string\.xml$).+\.(?:xml|json)$/i` is specific for `file_name_unwanted_string.xml` and not any other file ending with `_unwanted_string.xml`, so no

Comment: @trincot no it does not

Comment: Why not? Did you try using the negative look ahead in that reference? I don't see it in your attempt... Yet that is what is the solution. The comment of anubhava is the right idea, but just leave out `file` as that is not part of the string you want to exclude.

Comment: Use `/^(?!.*_unwanted_string\.xml$).+\.(?:xml|json)$/i`

Answer (score -2):

The question is quite incomplete regarding the environment used.
**Assuming** you have access to a python console you could run something like this:

```py
import re
import os

l = ( "file_name_unwanted_string.xml",
       "SOMEOTHERNAME_unwanted_string.xml",
       "NAME3_unwanted_string.xml",
       "NAME3_unwanted_string_MORE_TEXT.xml",
       "good_file.xml",
       "bad_unwanted_string_good.xml",
)
# or, assuming the current directory has the files you are interested in
# l = os.listdir()

[i for i in l if not re.search(r"(?=_unwanted_string)(.+)[.]xml$", i)] 

>>> ['good_file.xml']
```

You could of course change `l` by `os.listdir`